# Calling Javascript function only after getting the user details

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm currently using it with Firebase. I have two files, index.html and index.js, and I want to retrieve the user information from Firebase before proceeding with any other actions. I'm wondering how I should structure my JavaScript code to achieve this.

Currently, when I run my code, the function in index.html executes immediately and looks for the _db reference in index.js. It then runs the getData function, but at this point, I haven't yet retrieved the user information.

I know that I can retrieve the user information using the onAuthStateChanged function, which only executes once the user has been authenticated. However, if I try to put this function in the function() block of index.js, I receive an error message saying that _db is not defined.

Could you provide guidance on how to structure my code to ensure that the onAuthStateChanged function runs first and retrieves the user information before executing the getData function?

This is my index.html

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            
          </style>
        
            <script src="./index.js"></script>
            
            <script>
              $(function() {
                
                $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
                  width: "100%",
            height: "90%",
            heading: true,
            insertRowLocation: "top",
            loadMessage: "Please, wait ...",
            noDataContent: "Try Reloading once .. ",
                        filtering: true,
                        editing: true,
                        inserting: true,
                        sorting: false,
                        paging: true,
                        autoload: true,
                        confirmDeleting: true,
                        pageSize: 15,
                        pageButtonCount: 5,
                        pageLoading : true,
                        deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the this Row?",
                        controller: _db,
                        rowRenderer: null,
            headerRowRenderer: null,
            filterRowRenderer: null,
            insertRowRenderer: null,
            editRowRenderer: null,
                pagerRenderer: null,
                        fields: [              
                            { name: "name", type: "text", width: 150 },
                            { name: "uid", type: "number", width: 200 },                    
                            { type: "control",align: "center"}
                        ],
        });
              });
          </script>
          </head>
          <body class="myclass">
           // this is the body with sign in button and sign our
          </body>
        </html>
```

This is my index.js

```
            const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
            const firebaseconfig = initializeApp({ 
                // firebase configs
             });
            
             var signInBtn = document.getElementById("signInBtn");
             var signOutBtn = document.getElementById("signOutBtn");
             const auth = getAuth(firebaseconfig);
             
             signInBtn.onclick =  () => { 
             signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
              .then((result) => {
                const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
                console.log(result);
                const token = credential.accessToken;
                const user = result.user;
                jsGrid.hidden = false ;    
               
                console.log(user);
              }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                alert.hidden = false ;     
                alert.textContent = error.message;
                const email = error.customData.email;
                const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
              });
            }
            
            signOutBtn.onclick = () => {signOut(auth)}
            
            onAuthStateChanged(auth , user => {
                if(user!=null){
                console.log('user is logged in ');
                }else {
                   console.log('user is not loggedin ');
                }
            })
            
            const db = getFirestore(firebaseconfig);
            const db_name = "tesint";
            const collectionRef = collection(db, db_name);
            
            (function() {
                
                var _db = {
                    loadData: function(filter) {
            
                        return getData(filter) ;
                    }
            
                };
            
            async function getData(filter){
                 // getting the dat a
            }
```

Comment: To be honest, it looks like you could use some polishing alltogether. The simple answer would be to move onAuthStateChanged down to the bottom of the file, but that's just working around the problem instead of fixing stuff. Try to create a class around these methods with useful method names and move the initialization of the database to a method called first from the constructor with private properties as reference to the DB. Then call the authentication method and do your things after authentication with the public properties.

Comment: your `index.js` is missing some lines. it's not complete. move your js includes before the </body> tag (bc your script gets loaded first, then your DOM -> buttons do not exist but u query them). for your problem: as soon as your file is loaded, it executes its code. if i guess correctly (although lines are missing) your last call is an immediately invoked function. this is fine. you need to remove `$(function() {})` and use a simple function like `function getUserData() {}` and put this `$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({` stuff in there. And then call this `getUserData()` function where u want.